# Using ref parameter - Good design decision?

Tags: c#, software-design

In the context of c# I am a bit stuck in a self conflict about using ref/out parameters? Does the use of such parameters increase the coupling of methods or components I use?

I have no explicit example right now. I'm just curious on to know if it is a good software design to use this constructions.

IMHO the result of a method should be passed back through the return value of the method.

What's your opinion? This topic is more a design topic than a technical one.

Comment: If it's the right thing to do, it's the right thing to do. If not, it's not. I'm not sure what more can be said without the context of an actual example?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really have anything to do with coupling. It's a coding style. Personally, I dislike *ref*/_out_ parameters, especially when they're used to return multiple values from a function call. I prefer creating a custom class that wraps the intended return values, rather than returning multiple *out* params.

Comment: that's exactly what i would also prefer to do

Answer (score 1):

For normal cases i didn't think it's a good design decision to pass the parameter by reference.

Because you don't know what the function doing for that object.

Functions should be decoupled to really identify its role.

Answer (score 0):

What if you have to return more than 1 value? If the return value denotes success/failure and you also need to return certain calculated/processed values?

For example 'ref' parameters are required when the method needs to reassign a reference type.

The use would be governed more by the specific use case in question.

Comment: And my questions is if it is a good coding style to act like this. I just found a gooding guide line from MS to activate in code analysis. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182131%28v=vs.100%29.aspx Why would they state this, if there is no reason for?

Comment: As the link suggests..it is not advisable for 'general audience'. If your particular use case can do without it then you should avoid it. Else it then boils down to whether you would want to define a new type to return multiple return values or use a couple of ref parameters instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are some situations where it's useful to have both modifiers.
I just want to give you some examples about it.

### out

The dictionary is a good example for the use of the out parameter. If you want to know if the dictionary contains a key and want to retrieve the value if the key exists you are doing this this way:

```
MyType result;
if (myDictionary.TryGetValue(myKey, out result))
{
    // Use result
}
```

If you can't use the out parameter you would have to write it this way:

```
Dictionary<KeyType, MyType> myDictionary = ...;
if (myDictionary.ContainsKey(myKey))
{
    MyType result = myDicionary[myKey];
}
```

This would result in a performance impact, because the dictionary has to search for the key two times. The other possibility would be this:

```
Dictionary<KeyType, MyType> myDictionary = ...;
Dictionary<KeyType, MyType>.TryGetResult result = myDictionary.TryGetValue(myKey);

if (result.Succeeds)
{
    MyType resultValue = result.Value;
}
```

Which is useable but is in my eyes not as fine as the out solution because you have to create a extra struct or class for the result and, of course, the code is not so clean as well.

### ref

Ref is usefull when it's necessary to change a existing object outside the method which is called.

```
MyObject myvar = myStream.ReadMyObject();
if (dataProcessor.Process(ref myvar)) {.... }


// Data processor....
public Boolean Process(ref MyObject myvar)
{
    if (!myvar.IsClean)
    {
        myvar = new MyObject(); // Create clean object
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Your examples are of HOW these modifiers are used, technically. The OP was about design decisions - _should_ I write methods that modify an existing object? _Should_ I write methods that return one output as a return value and another as an _out_ parameter?

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan Theese examples show why it's useful to use them in some cases AND of  course also showing how to use them. It's a design desicion and what stays in your head, a text of 50 lines or a small sample of code. Especially for the out sample i made a good sample in which cases it could be useful to use the modifier.